# Stuck at deleting node from Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have been trying to follow the textbook "Introduction to Algorithms" but I'm stuck at the following step when deleting a node from a BST - when the node to be deleted has both children

My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bst.h"


void error()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error assigning memory to node");
    exit(1);
}

void insert(node **root, int key)
{
    node *t1, *t2;

    if (*root == NULL) {
        printf("Root is null\n");
        *root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (*root==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Cannot allocate memory for node in Insert");
            exit(1);
        }
        (*root)->key = key;
        (*root)->left = (*root)->right = NULL;
    }
    else {
        printf("Root contains data. Inserting new node.\n");
        t1 = *root;

        while (t1 != NULL) {
            t2 = t1;

            if (key < t1->key)
                t1 = t1->left;
            else
                t1 = t1->right;
        }

        if(key < t2->key) {
            t2->left = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
            t2 = t2->left;
            if (t2==NULL)
                error();
            t2 -> key = key;
        }
        else {
            t2->right = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
            t2 = t2->right;
            if (t2==NULL)
                error();
            t2->key = key;
        }
    }

    
}

void inorder(node * root)
{
    if (root!=NULL) {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d ->", root->key);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

node * search(node *root, int key)
{
    node * t = root;

    while (t!=NULL)
    {
        if (key == t->key)
            return t;
        else if (key < t->key)
            t = t->left;
        else
            t = t->right;
    }
    return NULL;
}

node * getparent(node * root, int key)
{
    node * t = root, *parent = NULL;

    while (t!=NULL)
    {   
        if (key == t->key)
            return parent;
        else if (key < t->key)
            t = t->left;
        else
            t = t->right;
        parent = t;
    }
    return NULL;
}

node * delete(node *root, int key)
{
    node * todelete = search(root,key), *parent = getparent(root, key), *y;
    if (todelete==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Key not found");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (todelete->left == NULL && todelete->right==NULL) { //Deleting node with no children
        if (todelete == parent->left)
            parent->left = NULL;
        else
            parent->right = NULL;
        free(todelete);
        return root;
    }
    else if (todelete->left && !todelete->right) {
        if (todelete == parent->left)
            parent->left = todelete->left;
        else
            parent->right = todelete->right;
        free(todelete);
        return root;
    }
    else if (todelete->right & !todelete->left) {
        if (todelete == parent->left)
            parent->left = todelete->left;
        else
            parent->right = todelete->right;
        free(todelete);
        return root;
    }
    else
    {
        node * yparent = NULL;
        y= todelete->right;
        while (y->left!=NULL)
        {
            y = y->left;
            yparent = y;
        }
        if(yparent != todelete) {
            //stuck here
        }
    }


}
```

bst.h:

```
struct treenode
{
    int key;
    struct treenode *left;
    struct treenode *right;
};

typedef struct treenode node;

node * getparent(node * root, int key);
void insert(node **root, int key);
node * search(node *root, int key);
node * delete(node *root, int key);
void inorder(node * root);
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. I should be trying to set the y = y->right and then set todelete->right = y correct?

Comment: What is parent supposed to be?

Comment: @stark parent is supposed to be the parent node of the tobedeleted child

Comment: Where is the definition of `node`?

Comment: You don't check for null parent

Comment: Do you want to delete *only a node*, keeping its children or to delete the children as well?

Comment: @Bob__ Delete only a node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code to the following and it works (for the delete functions):

```
static void transplant(node * root, node * u, node * v)
{
    node *uparent = getparent(root, u->key);
    node * vparent = getparent(root, v->key);

    if (uparent == NULL)
        root = v;
    else if (u == uparent->left)
        uparent->left = v;
    else uparent->right = v;

    if (v!=NULL)
        vparent = uparent;
}

node * delete(node *root, int key)
{
    node * todelete = search(root,key), *parent = getparent(root, key), *y;
    if (todelete==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Key not found");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (todelete->left == NULL && todelete->right==NULL) { //Deleting node with no children
        if (todelete == parent->left)
            parent->left = NULL;
        else
            parent->right = NULL;
        free(todelete);
        return root;
    }
    else if (todelete->left && !todelete->right) {
        if (todelete == parent->left)
            parent->left = todelete->left;
        else
            parent->right = todelete->left;
        free(todelete);
        return root;
    }
    else if (todelete->right && !todelete->left) {
        if (todelete == parent->left)
            parent->left = todelete->right;
        else
            parent->right = todelete->right;
        free(todelete);
        return root;
    }
    else {
        y = todelete->right;
        while(y->left!=NULL)
        {
            y = y->left;
        }

        node *yparent = getparent(root, y->key);
        if (yparent != todelete)
        {
            transplant(root, y, y->right);
            y->right = todelete->right;
            node * yrightparent = getparent(root, y->right->key);
            yrightparent = y;
        }
        transplant(root, todelete, y);
        y->left = todelete->left;
        node *yleftparent = getparent(root, y->left->key);
        yleftparent = y;
        free(todelete);
        return root;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm stuck at the following step when deleting a node from a BST - when the node to be deleted has both children

It follows from the properties of a BST that if a node **N** has two children then every node in the subtree rooted at the left child is less than every node in the subtree rooted at the right child and *vise versa*.  In particular, the largest node in the left subtree, **L<sub>max</sub>**, is less than all the nodes in the right subtree, and the least node in the right subtree, **R<sub>min</sub>**,  is larger than all the nodes of the left subtree.  These are the nodes immediately preceding and following **N** in an in-order traversal.  Both of those descendants are easy to find, and neither has more than one child (else they could neither be max nor min in any subtree).

It follows, then, that if you want to delete node **N** then you may choose either **L<sub>max</sub>** or **R<sub>min</sub>**, delete it from the tree (which is easy because it has at most one child), and replace **N** with it.  Alternatively, delete **L<sub>max</sub>** or **R<sub>min</sub>**, and replace the key of node **N** with the key of that deleted node.

Comment: @g0d, whether this is for self-motivated study or for an organized class, you will gain much more from working out an implementation yourself than from being given one.  Inasmuch as you are studying algorithms, understanding the principles and how to think about the problem is more important than the code.

Comment: I learn better from code samples. I've been struggling with this and at the verge of giving up. So the options are to either give up or get some code

Comment: @g0d Procede by little steps. Consider the last paragraph of this answer, can you write a function that given a root node finds the leftmost child node of it (and maybe the "distance" from the root)?

Comment: The code posted already finds the leftmost child node from a given node...

Comment: @g0d, translating words into code is among the most essential skills for a programmer.  If that is difficult for you then only practice will help you improve, and I decline to participate in denying you that opportunity.  You said "Any guidance would be much appreciated," and *guidance* is what I'm giving you.  I'm sorry you find that disappointing.

Comment: The words themselves aren't good enough to translate to code. Delete the answer pls

Comment: Your answer assumes deleting a node. My question was specific to deleting a node with two child nodes. So it DOES NOT ANSWER THE QUESTION.

Comment: @g0d, this answer specifically addresses deleting nodes with two children: "if a node N has two children then [...]".  It assumes that the one- and zero-child cases are already under control, since those are simpler, and you did not ask about them.  But in any case, do not be absurd.  If I had responded to a more general question than you asked, then that would not for that reason fail to be responsive to a more specific question.